# Number Constructor Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can we use number constructor to solve the problem below?

Write a function that converts a number to a euro string on top of the Number constructor?

so we can test function like `(100).toEuroString()`

Comment: `Number.prototype.toEuroString = function() { /*...*/ };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Number class and instanciate the constructor in the prototype.

```
Number.prototype.toEuroString = function() {
    // your function here
    // access the number value with this
}
```

for example let's say that you want to add a euro symbol to it you would use

```
Number.prototype.toEuroString = function() { 
    return "€" + this;
};
```

and you can use it as you specified

```
alert((100).toEuroString()); //alerts €100
```

see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/cxLvabm4/3/